# Why does this recursive function exceed maximum length in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
#finds length of a list recursively, don't understand why it exceeds maximum length, can someone please explain?
def lengtho(xs):

    if(xs == None):
        return 0
    return 1 + lengtho(xs[1:])


lengtho([1,2,3,4,1,4,1,4,1,1])
```

Comment: `[]` is not the same as `None`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new to python syntax

Comment: Try `if not xs:`

Answer (score 4):

When the code reaches the end of the list (the base case), `xs` will be equal to `[]` (the empty list), not `None`.  Since `[][1:]` simply returns `[]`, the function will call itself until the stack overflows.
The correct way to write this function in python would be:

```
def lengthof(xs):
   """Recursively calculate the length of xs.
      Pre-condition: xs is a list"""
   if (xs == []):
     return 0
   else:
     return 1+ lengthof(xs[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your base case of recursion will never get to `True` value, `xs == None` will be always `False` if you are talking about lists, probably you want to change it to `xs == []` or just `if not xs`